# Shadow between two columns

Tags: wpf, shadow

I've a grid and want to draw a shadow between the first and the second column. Whats the best way to add only a shadow on the left side of one specific column?

```xml
    <Grid Width="500" Height="300">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid>
```

I've tried to add an border to the second column but the border is still visible (it should now) and with a transparent border brush the shadow also disappear.

```xml
        <Border Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1 0 0 0"
                Opacity="1">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="-180"
                                  ShadowDepth="1"
                                  Color="Red" />
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own shadow effect using gradients -

```
    <Border  Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="#55FF0000" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
```

You can control depth, color, width, direction... of shadow by changing values of `Width` of `Border`, `StartPoint`, `EndPoint`, `GradientStop.Offset`, `GradientStop.Color`...